# knex missing table name from query

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I have a NodeJS server that runs Express and SQLITE.

When I do:

```
    const knexx = await knex('Users')
        .where({id: user.id})
        .update({ password: pwhashed }).toString()
    console.log(knexx)
```

Somehow it prints:

> update  set `password` =
>   '$2a$08$/qIkAQfaqzkwtXHyV.94S.YJ8OMx0e8nrySW6idCueZIT/f5rdU4K' where
>   `id` = 1

The queries are missing table names. When I get rid of .toString, it gives me:

```
{ [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "set": syntax error] errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }
```

Comment: Your query should work. Is there anything else we should know?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this implicates that the table `Users` doesn't exist (or what is less possible knexjs expects it should be written in lowercases even if SQLite table names are case insensitive), this could be easily checked using:

```
knex.schema.hasTable('Users').then(function(exists) {
  if (!exists) {
       console.log('table doesnt exist');
    });
  }
});
```